# 'a/an' before acronyms: British vs American

Tags: pronunciation, indefinite-article, transatlantic-differences

I learned English grammar by reading a few books published by [OUP](https://corp.oup.com/) (a British organization/company). According to the books, what determines whether '*a*' or '*an*' is used before a countable noun is not the first letter of the noun but how it is pronounced. So, '*an*' should be used before acronyms like 'MNO' and 'FMD' because their first letters are pronounced as /em/ and /ef/. But I've seen on the web that many times people use '*a*' with such acronyms, and it seems that many of those people are well-educated native English speakers. Is this a difference between British English and American English?

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between American English and British English when choosing an indefinite article before a letter, acronym or initialism. Not everything you read on the web is 'correct', even if the writer seems (to you) to be 'well educated'. Also people often make typing or editing errors and do not notice them later, or may be too lazy to correct them.

> The general rule for indefinite articles is to use a before consonants
> and an before vowels. The trick here is to use your ears (how the
> acronym is pronounced), not your eyes (how it's spelled).

[American Psychological Association style blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/04/using-a-or-an-with-acronyms-and-abbreviations.html)

Comment: Also, I wonder if some people may use 'a' when they would also pronounce 'the' as 'thuh' (before a consonant), and 'an' where they would say 'the' as 'thee' (before a vowel), and this is subject to considerable regional variation (some dialects never say 'thee').

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is the correct rule here. There is no special rule for *initialisms* (those are not "acronyms" -- and there's no special rule for acronyms either). The only rule for choosing between "a" and "an" is the pronunciation of whatever comes after it, no matter what it is.

The *[initialisms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initialism)* "MNO" and "FMD" are pronounced by their letters, so it's "***an** MNO*", "***an** FMD*", and "***a** PTA*".

*[Acronyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acronym)* like "NASA" and "ASCII" are pronounced as words spelled with those letters, so it's "***a** NASA flight*" and "***an** ASCII character*".

There are some other cases where initials are used as a shorthand for a whole word, rather than as an initialism, so if the writer expects the reader to pronounce the full word, they select "a" or "an" accordingly.

For instance, I often use "fb" rather than typing out the full name "Facebook" because I'm saying "Facebook" in my mind, so I type, "***a** fb post*".

So again, there is no other rule for "a/an" beyond the pronunciation rule, and it is followed 100% by native speakers of standard varieties of English in all speech and writing, no matter what type of word follows it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and teaching me that acronyms are different from initialisms. :)

Comment: @apadana You're welcome! Note that many (most?) native speakers incorrectly use the word "acronym" for initialisms and have never heard the word "initialism", so in the real world, feel free to say "acronym". In here with us word nerds, "initialism" is the better choice :)

Comment: _so I type, "a fb post"_ I would find that grossly unnatural. I would read it as 'a eff bee post'. I think attempting to second guess what happens in peoples' minds is a tricky business.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I expect you're in the minority. That's completely normal where I come from.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you - _You can create an FB post on various quizzes, With an FB post generator by your side, it's easier than ever to create stellar social media content at scale,_  Quite academic: _Sixty-one undergraduates with low or high SA were asked to use FB in a laboratory setting, to make an FB post, and to imagine three ambiguous FB scenarios_ (US National Institutes of Health). 117,00 Google hits for "an FB post". But only 87,000 for "a FB post".

Comment: I note that Cambridge Dictionary agrees with you (and me) that an acronym has to be pronounceable as a word, but Merriam-Webster seems less certain, adding: _also : an abbreviation (such as FBI) formed from initial letters : INITIALISM._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's a remarkably slim majority considering how informal and how recent the shift is, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @the-baby-is-you Yes, it's not wildly far off 50-50, which suggests that both conventions are OK (that it's a matter of preference).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've adjusted my post about how I use "fb" rather than "Facebook", because you're right, I'm going based on what I'm hearing in my own mind, rather than what I expect my reader is hearing. Years ago, after texting "an FB post" to a fellow teacher, she asked me (out loud), "***An** Facebook post??*" and the rest of the staff room agreed that "fb" in a text message is pronounced "Facebook", just as "FWIW" is pronounced "For what it's worth", rather than "effdoubleyouayedoubleyou".

Comment: I am something of a dinosaur with text messages; always 'you', never 'u', I take inordinate care to avoid spelling errors, proper nouns start with a capital letter, initialisms are in capitals, etc. I would have defended myself robustly to that teacher.